# Why printf("") is different from fprintf(stdin,"")?

Tags: c, printf

I find a strange thing. if I use `printf("hello\n")`, it will display "hello" and after 1 second, display "world". But if I use `fprintf(stdin,"hello\n")`, it just display "world" after 1 second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");      // fprintf(stdin,"hello\n");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr,"world\n");
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why two functions behave differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stdin` file handle is the standard *input* handle, not the standard output handle.

The ISO C standard specifically states that standard input is "for reading conventional input" and makes no mention of the ability to write to it.

In other words, your two snippets `printf(x)` and `fprintf(stdin, x)` (for arbitrary `x`) are *not* the same thing. The `fprintf` equivalent would be `fprintf(stdout, x)`.